# не отправляется jquery post, очень нужна помощь. Мистика:)

Tags: php, jquery

Код должен работать следующим образом:
Заходим на файл 1. Он отправляет post запрос на файл 2. Файл 2 пишет пост в лог и отправляет пост запрос на файл 3. Файл 3 пишет пост в лог.

Но файл 2 либо не делает пост, либо делает его неудачно, но при этом лог его пишется. Т.е. запрос на него приходит.

Если напрямую зайти в файл 2, то пост отправится и в файле 3 будет лог.

Т.е. проблема в том, что когда "машина" обращается к файл 2, он пишет лог, но пост запрос не отправляет. А когда человек на него заходит - все ок, запрос отправляется в файле 3 есть лог. Как так? Что делать? Помогите!:)

файл 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post( "http://site2.com/файл 2", { status: "ok" } );
</script>
```

файл 2

```
<?php
require_once 'helpers/log.php';
addLog($_POST);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.post( "http://site1.com/файл 3", { command: "delete" } );
    </script>
}
```

файл 3

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site2.com");
require_once 'helpers/log.php';
addLog($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо заменить "файл 2", например, на такой код

```
<?php
require_once 'helpers/log.php'; 
addLog($_POST);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://site1.com/файл 3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "command=delete");

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Когда "машина" обращается к файл 2, он пишет лог, но пост запрос не
>   отправляет"

А где, по вашему, должен выполниться JS-код в случае, когда к файлу 2 обращается "машина"?

В случае с "человеком" этот код выполняет движок V8, встроенный в браузер.

Comment: Это можно как-то обойти?

Comment: Например через curl